# Javascript and Anchor Tags, Best Practice?

Tags: javascript, html

Quick Question.

Should we put Javascript in the HREF or use onClick (event)?

Are there any pros/cons to using either one. Personally I think it's easier/cleaner to simply put code in the href, and not have to return false or worry about jumping to #

Are there any known browser specific issues with each method...

Examples:

```
<a href="javascript: alert('foo!');">Click Me</a>
<a href="#" onClick="alert('foo!');return false">Click Me</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('foo!');">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: You should externalize javascript code. Hear for the click event of the a tag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) Rather use onclick. Be sure to have a rational fallback URL in `href` when JS is not allowed.

2) Rather than `onclick="..."`, you should use event handler.
   Find elements using jQuery or XPath, and then for each, call `element.addEventListener()`.

```
element.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("bar"); }, false);
```

Or the old way...

```
element.onclick = function() { alert("foo"); };
```

Answer (score 8):

Keeping the code separate from the html is cleaner IMO.

```
<a id="foo" href="#">Click Me</a>
```

Then in head or separate js file:

```
document.getElementByID("foo").onclick = function() { alert("hi"); }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would personally not put the JavaScript code in the HTML.  You should use an event listener that will get triggered when the `<a>` is clicked on.

```
<a href="#" id="linkA">Click Me</a>
```

And then:

```
document.getElementById('linkA').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents page from scrolling to the top
    alert('foo!');
});
```

Comment: cool stuff on the .preventDefault method. Is this generally considered better than returning false at the end of the inline code?

Comment: @thesocalhacker: It's usually preferred to do it this way (with event handlers, not inline code).  You want to keep your JavaScript separate from your HTML, so yeah, `e.preventDefault();` is preferred (compared to returning false from inline code).

Answer (score 0):

In the onclick event (although assigned with JS rather then the attribute) with a sensible href attribute. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would externalize JavaScript but use the`href` to call it:

`<a href="javascript:foo('bar!');">Click Me</a>`

Although I think your quick `alert` example is fine as an exception to the rule.

However, if your using a JS library like jQuery you can of course assign events directly - see the first example in jQuery tutorial which looks at the anchor element [http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aHow_jQuery_Works)