# Is there a best practice for calling JavaScript with parameters from an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have read the following question

[Javascript and Anchor Tags, Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791321/javascript-and-anchor-tags-best-practice)

And it seems to suggest a solution such as the following

```
<a id="foo" href="#">Click Me</a>

document.getElementByID("foo").onclick = function() { alert("hi"); }
```

However suppose that I have a bunch of links all calling the same function with a different parameter.  My quick and dirty solution would be to generate something like the following

```
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction('1001');return false">Click Me 1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction('1002');return false">Click Me 2</a>
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction('1003');return false">Click Me 3</a>
```

Is there a way to adapt the listener solution to deal with parameters?

Comment: Depends what the parameters are. If they're just auto-incrementing numbers like you show here, you can easily write code to generate them for you. If not, it may or may not make sense to put the parameters in an array and automatically generate indexes into that.

Comment: You tagged the question "jQuery", does that mean jQuery is allowed to use? It sure makes event handling a lot easier...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a data attribute along these lines on each element in question:

```
<a href="#" id="foo" data-id="1000">Click Me 1</a>​
```

And use the following callback:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function() { 
    alert(this.getAttribute('data-id'));
}​
```

In fiddle form [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/qxXSb/).

A better option, though, might be to use jQuery to handle things. Assuming the link format above, that would look like this:

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

Comment: Updated with a jQuery alternative

Comment: You can use `$(this).data('id')` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegation.

```
<div id='links'>
<a href="#" class="link" data-param1='1000' data-param2='something'>click</a>
<a href="#" class="link" data-param1='1001' data-param2='something'>click</a>
<a href="#" class="link" data-param1='1002' data-param2='something'>click</a>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$links = document.getElementById("links");

$links.onclick=function(e){
  element = e.target;
  if(element.tagName="a" && element.getAttribute("class")=="link"){
    console.log(element.getAttribute("data-param1"))
    console.log(element.getAttribute("data-param2"));
  }
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you have in HTML a code like that:

```
<a href="#" id="foo" onClick="myFunction('1001');return false">Click Me 1</a>
```

It's exactly the same to have in JS:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function(event) {
    myFunction('1001');
    return false;
}
```

When the parser found an event attribute, it creates an anonymous function in exactly the same way.