# How do I run a javascript function from an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

There are a number of web sites including StackOverflow that have tried to answer this question. But I don't understand them. I'm hoping someone can show me what I'm doing wrong and explain it in very simple words... for me to understand.

How do I execute my javascript function from an  tag?

I have this html:

```
<span class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropbtn">Reports &nbsp;||&nbsp;</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="NCMMaps.php" target="_blank">Map All Members</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="ics214(); return false;">ICS214</a>
    </div>
</span>
```

The 'Map All Members' works great, but the 'ICS214' fails, with this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND logdate =
>   (SELECT min(logdate) FROM NetLog WHERE netID = )' at line 8' in
>   /var/www/html/sbr/ics214.php:24 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/sbr/ics214.php(24): PDO->query('SELECT min(logd...') #1
>   {main} thrown in /var/www/html/sbr/ics214.php on line 24

My Javascript look like this;

```
function ics214() {
    var str = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {  
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("netBody").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ics214.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Below is the php/MySQL part. But it runs fine and produces the report I need. I don't see an error here. But perhaps the way I'm passing the 'Q' value is the error?

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    require_once "dbConnectDtls.php";

    $q = $_GET["NetID"]; 

    $sql1 = ("SELECT min(logdate) AS minlog, 
                     DATE(min(logdate)) AS indate, 
                     TIME(min(logdate)) AS intime, 
                     DATE(max(timeout)) AS outdate, 
                     TIME(max(timeout)) AS outtime, 
                     activity, fname, lname, netcontrol, callsign 
              FROM NetLog 
              WHERE netID = $q AND logdate = (SELECT min(logdate) 
                FROM NetLog 
                WHERE netID = $q ) ");
    foreach($db_found->query($sql1) as $row) {

        $fname  = $row[fname];  $lname   = $row[lname];     $activity = $row[activity];
        $indate = $row[indate]; $outdate = $row[outdate];   $netcntl = $row[callsign];
        $intime = $row[intime]; $outtime = $row[outtime];
            if ($row[netcontrol] == "PRM") {$netcontrol = "Net Control Operator"; $netopener = $row[callsign];};
    }
?>
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax` - this is not a javascript error, you are running  `ics214()` in a manner that isn't incorrect ... the error is in `ics214.php` which you have neglected to show

Comment: post the query and php for this

Comment: To put what @JaromandaX said in simpler words, you have a javascript function named``ics214()`. Whan you click on `ICS214` link, this function fires and in this function you have an `ajax` call to the `ics214.php` file. you are also sending a parameter named `q` with the value of the `select1` element in your `html` to the `ics214.php` file. Now in this line of your JavaScript: `document.getElementById("netBody").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` you are showing the response of your `php` file and because you have errors in it, you see that error.

Comment: I've added the PHP and MySQL to the original post. But it works. I've been using it for some months, I only wanted to change where in my app that it was being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the $q value is resolving to an actual value? It looks like it may not be. In the SQL error feedback it says that there is an error in your syntax near the 'and SELECT.. ...netID =' which looks empty. If $q is empty there (value should show on stack trace after netID) it is going to be empty before AND clause. Meaning your SQL will now be 
WHERE netID = AND SELECT... that syntax will fail.

Update: I noticed that you are submitting the q value from your javascript 
 `xmlhttp.open("GET","ics214.php?q="+str,true);`

but in your PHP your trying to find 'NetID' from your $_GET array.

```
$q = $_GET["NetID"];
```

maybe you should either change the q in the js to NetID or vice versa.

Comment: I hardcoded the q value into the sql for testing. That means all I should have to do is call the function to run the php. This works. So you are correct, it is not getting the q value from in the javascript function. Why is the question. Its the same function I call from another link but without the anchor tag.

Comment: Would it be possible to call the PHP direct in the href? But I'd have to know the value of q. so I would have <a href="ics214.php?netID=5" but how do I get the 5?

Comment: Are you sure the element "select1" is in the DOM? I didn't see it in your posted code. Why don't you externalize your js and use events and listeners on the element.

Comment: take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791321/javascript-and-anchor-tags-best-practice